# All menu items are not displayed inside tieredmenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

All menu items are not displayed inside the `TieredMenu` in PrimeFaces. The list also appears above the `CommandButton`.

Following is the code:

```html
<p:commandButton id="adminButton" value="admin"/>
<p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="adminButton" my="left top" at="left bottom">
  <p:menuitem value="file" url=""/>
  <p:submenu label="Next">
    <p:menuitem value="edit" url=""/>
    <p:menuitem value="revert" url=""/>
  </p:submenu>
  <p:menuitem value="home" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit1" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit2" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit3" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit4" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit5" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit6" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit7" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit8" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit9" url=""/>
  <p:menuitem value="quit10" url=""/>
</p:tieredMenu>
```

How to make all the menus visible and they have to visible below the `CommandButton`. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Are there any surrounding components which might trigger this behavior? Can you try removing them?

Comment: also remove `my="left top" at="left bottom"` and see what the default behavior is it should be down unless there is a screen collision detected.